# Как передать параметр в вычисляемый атрибут, либо в ресурс?

Tags: php, laravel

Ребята, есть вопрос.
Есть кампании - у них есть вычисляемые поля, в зависимости от дат фильтрации.
В экшене мы должны отдавать коллекции ресурсов, ресурсы наследуются от JsonResource.

```
$to = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$campaigns = Campaign::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
$campaignResource = CampaignResource::collection($campaigns);
```

Задача в том, чтобы в `CampaignResource` передать список кампаний, атрибут `scope` должен вычисляться в зависимости от параметра `$to`.

Можно ли передать параметр `$to` в вычисляемый атрибут модели кампании?
Или решить задачу передав параметр в ресурс, чтобы вычислять значение атрибута в ресурсе?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас значение атрибута каждый раз вычесляеться динамически, то да имеет смысл используя [аксесеор](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) вычеслять его значение.
К примеру:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

И получаем:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$firstName = $user->first_name;
```